# Выполняется ли функция QPainter::setPen быстро?

Tags: qt, qt5, gui, производительность

Я рисую ломаную линию в вершинах которой рисуются кружки. Кружки рисуются без обводки.

```
void TimelineKeyframes::paintLine(QPainter* painter, const std::vector<QPointF>& line)
{
    QBrush brush(m_fillColor);
    painter->setBrush(brush);
    painter->setOpacity(m_opacity);

    QPen pen(m_lineColor, 1);

    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->drawEllipse(line[0], CircleRadius, CircleRadius);

    for (int i = 1; i < line.size(); ++i)
    {
        painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
        painter->drawEllipse(line[i], CircleRadius, CircleRadius);

        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->drawLine(line[i-1], line[i]);
    }
}
```

Функция QPainter::setPen вызывается много раз внутри цикла. У меня есть сомнения, хорошо ли это с точки зрения производительности. Насколько я знаю в 3D графике переключение материалов очень дорогая операция, поэтому там стараются как можно реже делать это. Но применимо ли это правило к 2D графике? Или всё таки оптимальней сделать два цикла?

```
void TimelineKeyframes::paintLine(QPainter* painter, const std::vector<QPointF>& line)
{
    QBrush brush(m_fillColor);
    painter->setBrush(brush);
    painter->setOpacity(m_opacity);

    QPen pen(m_lineColor, 1);

    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i)
        painter->drawEllipse(line[i], CircleRadius, CircleRadius);

    painter->setPen(pen);
    for (int i = 1; i < line.size(); ++i)
        painter->drawLine(line[i-1], line[i]);
}
```

Comment: по моему setPen это просто присвоение ссылки, но на всякий случай лучше посмотреть профайлером

Comment: мне кажется, быстрее было бы сделать бенч, тем более, что код на 90% готов